# How to improve or optimize a volume integration over a cuboid

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning

The volume integration over a cuboid is

```
V[d_] :=

Integrate[Boole[Abs[Sum[x[i], {i, 1, d}]] <= 1],

  Table[x[i], {i, 1, d}] ∈ Cuboid[Table[-1, {i, 1, d}], Table[+1, {i, 1, d}]]]
```

Comment: At d = 10 the calculation took one week on my machine.  So looking to reduce this time so that I can extend my calculation range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a version that's quicker:

```
v[d_] := With[{a = Array[x,d]},
    RegionMeasure @ ImplicitRegion[
        a ∈ Cuboid[-Table[1, d], Table[1, d]] && -1 < Total[a] < 1,
        a
    ]
]

AbsoluteTiming[v[#]]& /@ Range[10]
```

> {{0.01922, 2}, {0.016206, 3}, {0.020267, 16/3}, {0.036396, 
>     115/12}, {0.047995, 88/5}, {0.126135, 5887/180}, {0.15326, 19328/
>     315}, {0.622323, 259723/2240}, {0.996131, 124952/567}, {6.44973, 
>     381773117/907200}}

**Update**

It is possible to considerably speed up the computation of the integral. First, we can rewrite the integral as:

$$\int\limits_{-1<q, x_i<1} \delta\left(q - \sum_i x_i\right) d q \, d x_1 \
\dots d x_n$$

where the Dirac $\delta$-function is used to constrain the auxiliary variable $q$ to be equal to the sum of the $x_i$. Next, we use the integral representation of the Diract $\delta$-function:

$$\delta(q) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i q t} d t$$

to rewrite our integral as:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{-1<q, x_i<1, -\infty<t<\infty} e^{i t (q - \sum_i x_i)} d t \, d q \, d x_1 \dots d x_n$$

Then the $x_i$ and $q$ integrations are trivial, yielding:

$$\frac{2^{n+1}}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{\sin(t)^{n+1}}{t^{n+1}} d t$$

So, we can compute the integral using:

```
v2[n_] := 2^(n+1)/(2Pi) Integrate[Sin[t]^(n+1)/t^(n+1), {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Let's compare with my previous answer:

```
v2 /@ Range[10]
```

> {2, 3, 16/3, 115/12, 88/5, 5887/180, 19328/315, 259723/2240, 124952/567, 381773117/907200}

And let's check the timing for large dimensions:

```
v2[20] //AbsoluteTiming
v2[100] //AbsoluteTiming
v2[200] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.325792, 9093099984535515162569/28963119144960000}
>
> {2.1238, 1020874816282990019674410634879947005232148656344532945518475763614784650459294389295646398113477657001325527060302456147584151965435242421880829753275900273137105599368656629559922713/ 5865146772495233325898644975884030950899696346429212007830125936099648063928476345458865257425623321157220834642233770629159452672000000000000000000000000}
>
> {24.2113, 2105250721652230995822272046810873870413657347037560764530315691433745046783121212851654273572243798860903038716777668825145193210539476222986275208022163771704087074883916794754951725689972357505903741345245389968029635187558718196115410506215214997355078761172767134084048388280698491074446401113821960027596242780660090413848165382114127518127816699619836834010470350372430516992221219749467021223546494318827484062110668981/13450126771953861972742267237993923538333561482440622598217307355386093152150316273430330249410847584103635329094955068860033487953122040712758820475860617574295375877890871251131511456564743225144189655047367599338153112598059593252671310975759722968189377693419294052502911738854239771633258717703068691272534721560576000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}

Perhaps somebody can compute the integral for symbolic $n$.

Comment: This is correct, you have duplicated the results that I have from the slower method.  The speed up is about 100,000 times.